# Are any plot-trigger items dropped at the end of Tranquility?

Tags: dragon-age-2

The *Tranquility* quest ends with

> an ambush by templars, including a templar lieutenant and hunter.

I found this to be a very difficult bit of combat, but eventually succeeded... only to realise that since a cut scene across multiple locations immediately followed, I was unable to collect any loot from my vanquished foes.

I don't care about random trash-for-cash loot (unless, of course, it's a whole 50GP), and I can look up missed journal entries on the wiki. But are there any plot hooks or resolution tokens that would have been in this loot, that would necessitate me doing this again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no plot-relevant items as loot in this quest. (Usually, if a quest ends with cutscenes, there is nothing important to loot.)

You can get Ser Alrik's letter from the Templar Lieutenant (Ser Bardel), but all it unlocks is the codex entry 'Templar Letter'. The rest is random loot.

Also, remember you can always loot mid-combat.

Comment: Phew. I realised too late I could loot during combat, and the fight was hard enough that I didn't want to try again. But I did eventually go back and confirm this.